# Is it possible for a XDK cordova app to run as a background service in android and iPhone?

Tags: cordova, cross-platform, intel-xdk, background-service

I am new to XDK and cordova, I'm trying to figure out if it is possible to create a cordova app that can run as a background service in android and iPhone and also have the ability to restart itself upon a phone reboot.

From my research so far, it appears like this is not possible due to the whole web view concept. Can someone with more knowledge on this matter confirm this for me?

If it is not possible, does anyone have any suggestions as to what cross platform framework I can use that does support this?

Just a precaution before I start developing this app native on both platforms. Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Best,
Rob

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to run your webview in the background, but there have been some Cordova plugins that do run in the background. There are multiple examples in the form of a "[geolocation background](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=cordova%20plugin%20geolocation%20background)" plugin. I'm sure you can find others.

So if you are willing to create a plugin (or you might be lucky enough to find one) that performs the background operations you need, then you might be able to make it work. Of course, I can't say for certain, because it depends on your app and what you plan to do.

Note also that you can handle the various lifetime states within your Cordova app. That means that you can create event handlers for resume and pause, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your response and for confirming that a webview cannot run in the background. I will look into creating a plugin for cordova.